# Routes not found in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

I have 2 ways of loggin in to my app. the first way is to loggin via email the next one is loggin via social media.

I have installed devise and omniauth, omniauth-facebook,twitter and google plus. I have successfully implemented the normal login in via devise but when I try to login via fb or twitter or gplus by visiting /auth/facebook it says route not found.

```
    Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  root to: 'visitors#index'
  get '/auth/:provider/callback' => 'sessions#create'
  get '/signin' => 'sessions#new', as: :signin
  get '/signout' => 'sessions#destroy', as: :signout
  get '/auth/failure' => 'sessions#failure'
end
```

//session_controller.rb

```
    class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    redirect_to '/auth/facebook'
  end

  def create
    auth = request.env['omniauth.auth']
    user = User.where(provider: auth['provider'],
                      uid: auth['uid'].to_s).first || User.create_with_omniauth(auth)
    reset_session
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Signed in!'
  end

  def destroy
    reset_session
    redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Signed out!'
  end

  def failure
    redirect_to root_url, alert: "Authentication error: #{params[:message].humanize}"
  end
end
```

//omniauth.rb

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_KEY'], ENV['FACEBOOK_SECRET'],
           scope: 'public_profile', info_fields: 'id,name,link'
  provider :twitter, ENV['TWITTER_KEY'], ENV['TWITTER_SECRET']
  provider :google_oauth2, ENV['GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'], ENV['GOOGLE_SECRET'],
           scope: 'profile', image_aspect_ratio: 'square', image_size: 48,
           access_type: 'online', name: 'google'
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncommenting the

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
     :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable //, :omniauthable
```

in user.rb did the trick